# How to Downgrade an i386 / ia32-libs Library on Wheezy?

Tags: 32bit-64bit, libraries

I recently upgraded to an amd64 version of Wheezy, and I have a couple of compiled proprietary programs that need to keep running 32-bit.

No problem, I installed the i386 compatibility libraries

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Unfortunately, the version of one of the libraries installed is wrong, generating an error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libdb-4.6.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

It looks like I've got:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1641048 Jun 28  2012 i386-linux-gnu/libdb-5.1.so
```

Where my program expects:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1638052 Sep 13  2008 libdb-4.6.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     800 Sep 13  2008 libdb-4.6.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1256548 Sep 13  2008 libdb-4.6.so
```

What's the best way to backtrack the libraries to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you tried just symlinking a 4.6 to the 5.1 libs?

Comment: Interesting thought, but no go. After that link: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdb-4.6.so: version `DB4_6' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied my libdb-4.6.so file off of my old i386 machine into /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu and it seems to work fine.

Anyone want to tell me why this is a horrible idea? If not, this may be the answer ...

Comment: Considering the scope of use this library will have, I believe this *is* the correct answer.